# R - For loop with dplyr for subsetting data across multiple data frames

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, subset

I have 50 data frames with temperature and humidity data and I want to create a new data frame, which includes a specific row from each data frame. Firstly I've created a list (*onomata_list*) in which I imported all 50 data frames, secondly I've created a dummy data frame (*All_stations_30_6_17*) to "send" the rows from each data frame and finally I wrote the following for loop in order to achieve the abovementioned:

```
 for(i in 1:length(onomata_list)){
  new_df <- onomata_list[[i]] %>% filter(date == "2017-06-30" & time == "17:00")
  All_Stations_30_6_17 <- rbind(All_stations_30_6_17,new_df)
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, and I receive the following message:

Error in rbind(All_stations_30_6_17, new_df) :
object 'All_stations_30_6_17' not found

It tried to solve it for the last couple of hours, but I had no luck. Any suggestion ?

Comment: In the code you have posted, you have not created the variable `All_stations_30_6_17` before you use it. It would be helpful if you could post a small reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you have a list of dataframes:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

All_Stations_30_6_17 <- map_dfr(onomata_list, ~ filter(.x, date == "2017-06-30" & time == "17:00"))
```

Map functions generally iterate through list elements. Here `map_drc` will map the purrr-style function (denoted with the `~`) over the list elements of `onomata_list` and then row bind (hence the `_dfr`) into a dataframe output.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much not only for the solution, but for introducing me this new function!!

Comment: @H.Johnson The [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) is a collection of several very useful packages for data manipulation. `purrr` and `dplyr` are two of those packages, but I think you would find it helpful to learn these packages.

Comment: I will definitely do so LMc! Thanks again!!

Comment: hi again! I would like a little clarification regarding your code. It works perfectly if I want to create 1 dataframe from the contents of a list, but If I want to convert each list's element into a new dataframe, but keeping the filter for each and every new dataframe,  can I do it with an alteration of the abovementioned script ? I've been trying it for about 2 hours but I haven't manage to achieve it..

Comment: @H.Johnson then I would just use `map` instead of `map_dfr`, which is what converts the list into a single, stacked dataframe.